Dynamically generate and register an entity with Hibernate
I want to generate entities on the fly and register such entities with Hibernate at runtime, ideally I would like to do something similarly to what EclipseLink does with its Dynamic persistence: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic.
For example:
DynamicClassLoader dcl = new DynamicClassLoader(currentLoader);
Class<?> employeeClass = dcl.createDynamicClass(packagePrefix + "Employee");
JPADynamicTypeBuilder address = new JPADynamicTypeBuilder(addressClass, null, "D_ADDRESS");

address.setPrimaryKeyFields("ADDR_ID");
address.addDirectMapping("id", int.class, "ADDR_ID");
address.addDirectMapping("street", String.class, "STREET");
address.addDirectMapping("city", String.class, "CITY");
address.addDirectMapping("province", String.class, "PROV");
address.addDirectMapping("postalCode", String.class, "P_CODE");
address.addDirectMapping("country", String.class, "COUNTRY");

address.configureSequencing("ADDR_SEQ", "ADDR_ID");

Would that be possible in Hibernate? I saw long ago that I could create the persistency unit definition in the old XML way and load it somehow in Hibernate, would that be possible?
